# How to use azure-sqldb-spark connector in pyspark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-jdbc

I want to write around 10 GB of data everyday to Azure SQL server DB using PySpark.Currently using JDBC driver which takes hours making insert statements one by one.

I am planning to use azure-sqldb-spark connector which claims to turbo boost the write using bulk insert.

I went through the official doc: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark.
The library is written in scala and basically requires the use of 2 scala classes :

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
  "url"               -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "user"              -> "username",
  "password"          -> "*********",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Clients",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "2500",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
))

df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)
```

Can it be implemented in used in pyspark like this (using sc._jvm):

```
Config = sc._jvm.com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
connect= sc._jvm.com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

//all config

df.connect.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)
```

I am not an expert in Python. Can anybody help me with the complete snippet to get this done.

Comment: What help are you expecting ?

Comment: How to use azure-sqldb-spark connector in pyspark? I know it can be done in scala but my entire project is in python.

Comment: I think we don't have any examples yet please subscribe to this issue - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark/issues/20

Comment: Hey @AjayKumar How do you overcome performance issue in puspark? i am currently running into performance issue. Can you help me?

Comment: @AjayKumar The project in the github link you referenced is not being actively maintained anymore. Instead use the project in [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector). Microsoft encourages us to use this project that has support for Python and R bindings, an easier-to use interface to bulk insert data, and many other improvements.

Answer (score 7):

The Spark connector currently (as of march 2019) only supports the Scala API (as documented [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark)).
So if you are working in a notebook, you could do all the preprocessing in python, finally register the dataframe as a temp table, e. g. :

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('testbulk')
```

and have to do the final step in Scala:

```
%scala
//configs...
spark.table("testbulk").bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)
```

Comment: This works well. Before the connector is implemented in Pyspark, this workaround should do the job.

Comment: @huichen do you know how to add 'ldap" authorization in?

Comment: You mean add ldap auth to the cluster? You can try to add it in the init script so every time when the cluster is started, it will be installed.

Comment: @huichen can you elaborate this please